# Reactjs: How to add multiple instances

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Not sure the Title of this question describes what I'm struggling with. This is a jockey program. If I want to add multiple jockeys competing to finish a race, How do I do that? It was working for just one jockey, however, when I try to add a second/multiple jockeys, I get issues. Where am I failing in the logic?

**App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../../images/logo.svg';
import { Jockey } from './Jockey';
import './App.css';


export class App extends Component {

  // handleClick = () => {
  //   // const that = this;
  //   this.interval = setInterval(() => {
  //     this.setState((previousState) => {
  //       if(previousState.progress >= 99){
  //          return { progress:100 }
  //       }
  //       return { progress: previousState.progress + 1 }
  //     });
  //   }, this.state.interval);
  // }

  render() {
    const Buttons = () => (
      <div className="App-buttons">
        <button className="ui primary button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Start</button>
        <button className="ui button">Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to the React Race Hustle</h1>
        </header>
        {/* <Buttons /> */}
        <Jockey />
        {/* <Jockey /> */}
      </div>
      
    );
  }
}
```

**Jockey.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Progress from 'react-progressbar';

export class Jockey extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        avatar: "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/3757315?v=4",
        interval: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),
        progress: 0,
      }
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
  
    handleClick = () => {
      // const that = this;
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState((previousState) => {
          if(previousState.progress >= 99){
             return { progress:100 }
          }
          return { progress: previousState.progress + 1 }
        });
      }, this.state.interval);
    }
  
    render() {
    //   const Buttons = () => (
    //     <div className="App-buttons">
    //       <button className="ui primary button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Start</button>
    //       <button className="ui button">Reset</button>
    //     </div>
    //   );
  
      return (
        <div>
          {/* <Buttons /> */}
          <div className="App-field">
            <img src={this.state.avatar} alt=""/>
            <Progress className="App-progress" completed={this.state.progress}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  
  }
```

Comment: "I get issues": what kind of issues? It's good to be specific when you're describing failing code.

Comment: Could you please provide the error message? :)

Comment: Sorry the progress bar no longer functions with no errors.

Comment: Do you see any errors in console? Use Chrome F12 or if you use Firefox pless Ctrl+Shift-J to open error console. Some component may not work after some crash so we interesting in that message.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in your code, nothing can trigger the `handleClick` event in `Jockey` class, I assume you want one button in `App` class to start all jockeys at the same time.

There's different ways to do this :

1st Method : **Use a "toggle prop" to fire event in children :**

in Parent :

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ start: true });
}
...
<Jockey start={this.state.start} />
```

in Child :

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.start === false && nextProps.start === true) {
        this.startInterval(); // handleClick function in your case
    }
}
```

2nd Method : **Move the logic to the parent, be sure to use a different names to declare multiple setInterval.**

3rd Method : **Use the `ref` attribute to execute a child method :**

in Parent :

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.jockey1.handleClick();
    this.jockey2.handleClick();
}
...
<Jockey ref={jockey => { this.jockey1 = jockey } />
<Jockey ref={jockey => { this.jockey2 = jockey } />
```